# Why do i get return value ignored error when there is nothing to return?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

- xyz.cpp file

  ```
  void log(const char* message);

  void dummyfunc(const char* op) {
      log(*op);  // C6031: return value ignored
  }

  int main() {

    dummyfunc("Hello!");
  }
  ```
- Log.cpp file

  ```
  void log(const char* message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Log.cpp" << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- Output

  ```
  'DevC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
  The thread 0x46b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
  'DevC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
  'DevC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
  The thread 0x22c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
  The thread 0xcb0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
  The program '[9156] DevC++.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
  ```

I created a log function which accepts a const char* and returns nothing. This function is created in different .cpp file. Then I created another void function which calls this function. I dont get any error nor any output. The programm runs but "Hello!" and "Log.cpp" is not printed. And when i hover over the green underlined part, I see Error C6031: return value ignored. Is there anything to return in log function? What I understood from void is that it returns nothing or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text.

Comment: When you learned about splitting a program into more than one file, what did you learn about function declarations?

Comment: Your code should give you warnings, but *other* warnings than the one you claim. Please make sure to create a proper [mre] that you copy-paste *as text* into your question (**[edit]** your question for that), and then copy-paste the full and complete build log, also as text, into to your questions, and add comments in the code where you get problems.

Comment: every function returns at least void, it doesn't know what to return because it probably doesn't know what log is

Comment: You're calling the [logarithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) function. You don't get a compilation error because you erroneously dereferenced the argument.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm really new to C++ so I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. When i dereference the argument, I call logarithm function which returns something. Even though my functions are void, compiler thinks I'm ignoring the return value which is coming from logarithm. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. `*op` is a `char`, and can't be converted to `char*`,  so your function is not  considered. `char` is an integer, so it matches an overload of the standard `log` function, which does return a value.

Comment: Your code *still* isn't a [mre]. You don't show us header file you include, you don't show is you have `using namespace std;` (which is very relevant to this question and its problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have bunch of unrelated stuff inside the file thats why i just wanted to put only the things that are related to this issue. And I dont have using namespace std;. I learned its not good to use so im trying to avoid using it.

Comment: chicka: The problem with the code you posted is that it's incomplete and doesn't contain the error. You posted only what you *think* is relevant to the error. Construct a minimal reproducible example and 1) other users will have enough info to help you, and 2) you may just find the answer yourself along the way.

Answer (score 0):

change the argument of the log call in dummyfunc() from "*op" to op and the program will work correct.

```
    void dummyfunc(const char* op) {
       log(op);  // C6031: return value ignored
    }
```

The function argument "op" is already a pointer of the type const char*. So it is exact the type which you are using for the log().

Test:

```
    Hello!
    Log.cpp
```

Comment: Please do not keep the explanation *why* this change helps a secret.